Angular 17 not showing content when using variable inside
I'm using angular 17 with angular material and when I wanted to show simple string variable it disappear the whole content
html:
<h2 mat-dialog-title>Ticket</h2>

<mat-dialog-content>
    My ticket: {{ tekst }}
</mat-dialog-content>

<mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Close</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>

component
@Component({
selector: 'app-ticket-statistic',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatDialogTitle, MatDialogContent, MatButtonModule, CommonModule,  MatDialogActions, MatDialogClose, MatDialogModule],
  templateUrl: './ticket-statistic.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ticket-statistic.component.sass']
})


Where is tekst defined, and have you checked the console for errors?

I defined it in component and there is no errors

Please can you share via a stackblitz where the variable is defined?
